# Changing excel data via moving line chart

Tags: excel, charts, interactive, excel-2002

I am using excel 2002, i want to be able to move the marker on a line chart so that it changes the data.  I could only find one post that refers to this functionality. http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=138369

Excel built in help is no help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, it seems like you can do it automatically.  Straightforward if they're just values you've entered, if its a formula it brings up a goal seek box.